# How to initialize a lazy variable before rendering using provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, lazy-initialization

I want to initialize a variable before getting to the GoRouter routes.
This `authenticated` below is the variable I want to initialize:

```dart
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late bool? authenticated;
  static late User? user;

  AuthProvider() {
    checkAndNotify();
  }

  Future<bool?> checkAndNotify() async {
    try {
      String? token = ((await AppStorage.appBox.get("token")) as String?);
      authenticated = token!=null;
      notifyListeners();
      return authenticated;
    } catch (err) {
      logError(
        message: "Seems like the user is not authenticated",
        error: err.toString(),
        method: "check",
      );
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I added a constructor so that `checkAndNotify` will be called once the provider is created.

And this is where I try to access `authenticated`: `routes.dart`

```dart
final routes = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: "/",
  errorBuilder: (context,state) => const ErrorScreen(),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
        path: "/",
        redirect: (context, state) {
          if (context.watch<AuthProvider>().authenticated != true) {
            return "/auth/login";
          } else {
            return "/home";
          }
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: "auth",
            redirect: (context, state) {
              return "/auth/login";
            },
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: "login",
                builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
              ),
              GoRoute(
                path: "register",
                builder: (context, state) => const RegistrationScreen(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ShellRoute(
            restorationScopeId: "route.shell",
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: "home",
                name: "home",
                builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
              ),
              GoRoute(
                path: "orders",
                name: "orders",
                builder: (context, state) => const OrdersScreen(),
              ),
              GoRoute(
                path: "profile",
                name: "profile",
                builder: (context, state) => const ProfileScreen(),
              ),
            ],
            builder: (context, state, child) {
              return Shell(child: child);
            },
          ),
        ]),
  ],
)
```

Pay attention to:

```dart
redirect: (context, state) {
          if (context.watch<AuthProvider>().authenticated != true) {
            return "/auth/login";
          } else {
            return "/home";
          }
        },
```

This is how my `main.dart` looks like:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await dotenv.load();
  await AppStorage.init();
  await LanguageProvider.init();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => LanguageProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
      ],
      child: const Eshop(),
    ),
  );
}

class Eshop extends StatelessWidget {
  const Eshop({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: routes,
      theme: AppTheme.light,
    );
  }
}
```

When i run this code, I get a `LateInitializationError` then I get redirected as epxected to the `LogInScreen`. I guess that is because of the fact that `checkAndNotify` is asynchronous.
I also tried to modify the `Eshop` widget to be `stateful` in order to be able to call `checkAndNotify` inside `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` but it did not change anything:

```dart
class _EshopState extends State<Eshop> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(( timeStamp) {
      context.read<AuthProvider>().checkAndNotify();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: routes,
      theme: AppTheme.light,
    );
  }
}
```

**NOTE TO MY QUESTION**: I don't want to remove the `late` modifier like I saw in order's answer related to this kind of situation, What I want is know how to properly use it in my app so that authenticated won't ever be null or have a default value.

Comment: Welcome to SO! good job by properly formatting the question. 

How about using a `FutureBuilder` in your routes?

Comment: Could a Completer or Future help?  Basically marking something as "late" means that you are giving your word that you will initialize the variable before you try to use it.  You need to implement some way to make sure you are keeping your word.

Comment: Thank you @MendelG. Actually I don't know. I asked the question to get helps about what's is the best way to initalize the variable before accessing it. I thought about using `FutureBuilder` but I wasn't sure if it was appropriate. Yes it may work but I don't know if there are side effects.

Comment: @JohnWeidner This is actually my question. I don't want authenticated to have a default value and I don't want to access it before it's initialized.